# maven-war-plugin without maven-compiler-plugin how it works

Tags: maven

I've just downloaded a sample project off the internet which had this in the pom...

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

There was an error so what i did was to remove maven-compiler-plugin and then I ran the pom and it worked (i.e. the war file was created).

Why is the compiler plugin required? And what is happening here now that I have removed it? What compiler will it be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **maven-compiler-plugin** part is needed for changing default configurations. In this case, it was to set the JDK versions to 1.5.
You can manage without it if you don't have anything to compile, or are OK with the default values (I think 1.4).

I hope this helps.